# What are the possible type of arraylist we can pass in method(ArrayList<? super T> list) where T is an interface?

Tags: java, generics, collections

```
public interface Fruits {}

public interface SweetFruitsInterface extends Fruits{}

public class FruitParty <T extends Fruits> {
    public void getFruits(ArrayList<? super SweetFruitsInterface> fruitList) {
        System.out.println("Lets get Fruit List");
    }
}
```

Now to call this method as per my understanding I can pass an arrayList of SweetFruitsInterface type but other than that we can pass super classes of implementation class of SweetFruitsInterface and so I try to create one implementation of SweeFruitsInterface as below:

```
public class SweetProducts {}
public class SweetFruits extends SweetProducts implements SweetFruitsInterface{}
```

now I call the method

```
ArrayList<SweetProducts> sweetProductsArrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
fruitsFruitParty.getFruits(sweetProductsArrayList1);
```

But its giving compiler error?
May I know if this SweetProducts is not the super class of implementation class of SweetFruitsInterface , and if it is then why its not working..

I tested this with class scenario where T is super , but i wanna understand how this works for interface

Comment: "but other than that we can pass super classes of *implementation* class of SweetFruitsInterface" no, `<? super SweetFruitsInterface>` can accept superclass of `SweetFruitsInterface` *interface* (like `Fruits`), NOT supertype of *implementation* of that interface.

Comment: Thanks pshemo for the quick response!! so if I understood correctly we can pass only parent interface of X, in this scenario like Fruits or any other interface which is parent of Fruits also we can pass but we can not pass any implementation classes of any of those parent interface...

Comment: Yes. BTW you shouldn't limit yourself only to ArrayList. Instead you can use List which has similar API but allows us to pass other lists as well, like LinkedList, etc. See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947)

Comment: Thanks pshemo, i was stuck on this interface thing in generics so forgot to do that List thing ,but yes thats an important point while constructing the programs btw that was my first question on stackoverflow!! so really appreciate your suggestion